# Shift+Click Event Woes

Tags: jquery, events, click, shift, ctrl

I'm sure i'm doing something terribly stupid for this not to work, but I can't get my shift event to fire. I've tried both:

```
$('.ShowCannedReport_UserFilterDropdown').each(function (index, element) {
        $(element).bind('click', function (event) {
        if (!event.shiftKey && !event.ctrlKey) {
        ShowCannedReport_UserFilter_Blur(this, event);
        }
        else {
        ShowCannedReport_UserFilterWithShiftHeld = this;
        }
 });
```

and:

```
$('.ShowCannedReport_UserFilterDropdown').each(function (index, element) {
        $(element).click(function (event) {
            if (!event.shiftKey && !event.ctrlKey) {
                ShowCannedReport_UserFilter_Blur(this, event);
            }
            else {
                ShowCannedReport_UserFilterWithShiftHeld = this;
            }
        });
    });
```

Both of these show the event.shiftkey as undefined. Any idea as to what i'm doing wrong?

ShowCannedReport_UserFilterDropdown is a multiselect dropdown and the click event is firing on both versions, but the shiftkey event is never registered.

Comment: presumably its not working in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be sure that your initial selector is working? I.e:

```
$('.ShowCannedReport_UserFilterDropdown').length; //is this >0 ?
```

Is the code inside the document ready event handler?

I've set up a jsFiddle that mimics what you are trying to achive, and all works ok:
http://jsfiddle.net/xT4ke/

Also, why are you iterating through each item when jQuery does that for you, This should suffice:

```
$('.ShowCannedReport_UserFilterDropdown').click(function (event) {
        if (!event.shiftKey && !event.ctrlKey) {
            ShowCannedReport_UserFilter_Blur(this, event);
        }
        else {
            ShowCannedReport_UserFilterWithShiftHeld = this;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something dumb - I forgot to enclose it in a document.ready